# Azure metric alert dimension operator ARM-Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-oms

I want to exclude a Virtual Machine to an alert rule. I use ARM-Templates to deploy my alerts. The problem is that exclude won't work.

```
"dimensions": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Computer",
                                    "operator": "Exclude",
                                    "values": [ "VMname" ]
                                },
```

ISSUE: If I choose Exclude as operator. It performs the same as Include.

Anyone has the same Issue?

Answer (score 0):

Related question is raised in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/085a414a-8d63-48a3-a76d-c506ca2c29e3/alert-rule-dimension-operator-exclude-armtemplate?forum=opinsights) MSDN thread; Just sharing this for the benefit of broader audience who might face similar issue.